# Modal content not displaying correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, class, css, style

I am creating a lightning component that pops up from a button on Opportunity.

In this lightning component I am using multiple `recordEditForm` tags that are just outside `tab` tags.

When setting the classes it displays one form on the left but when going onto another tab that uses a different `recordEditForm` it pushes this form over to the right of the screen as if the other was still displayed.

Here is some snippets of my code that will hopefully help!

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container{
    height : auto;
    min-width: 90vw;
    }

    .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    }

    .customFooter{
    display: inline !important;
    }

</aura:html>
```

This is in my component to set the style of the pop up /\

```
<lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}" variant="vertical">
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Factfind2_0__c" aura:id="firstPage"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.submitFP}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                  class="slds-modal__content"
                                  >
            <lightning:tab label="Objectives" id="Objective">

                <h2>TFC Section</h2>
                <p>This is the record id {!v.recordId}</p>

                <div style="padding: 14px;">                

                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/> 
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
                    <p/><br/>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.listAccs}" var="acc">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!acc.AccountId}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="WantsImmediateTFC__c"/>
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="RequiredTFCAmount__c"/>
                </div>

                <p/><br/>

                <!-- Objectives table -->
                <table>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            Objective 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount 1
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Objective 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount 2
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Objective 3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount 3
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Objective 4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount 4
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

This is part of my tabset and one record edit form, included some of the table to show how its laid out to /\

```
 <lightning:tab label="Fact Find Complete" id="Complete">
            Fact Find has been completed!
        </lightning:tab>

        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Budget_Planner__c" aura:id="budgetPlanner">
        <lightning:tab label="Budget Planner" id="BudgetPlan">


                <h2>Budget Planner</h2>

                <table>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="MainEmploymentNetMonthlyIncome__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalAmountOfStateBenefits__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="OtherIncomeTotalAmount__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="PartnersNetMonthlyIncome__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalNetMonthlyIncomeWithPartner__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalNetMonthIncomeWithoutPartner__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X1MortgageOrRentalPayments__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X1PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X1ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X2LoanOrCreditCardRepayments__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X2PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X2ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X3OtherDebtPayments__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X3PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X3ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X4MonthlyUtilityExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X4PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X4ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X5MonthlyGroceryExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X5PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X5ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X6MonthlyClothingExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X6PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X6ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X7MonthlyPhoneAndInternetExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X7PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X7ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X8MonthlyEntertainmentExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X8PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X8ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X9MonthlyCarOrTravelExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X9PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X9ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X10MonthlyMaintenanceExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X10PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X10ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X11MonthlyNetPensionContributions__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X11PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X11ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X12MonthlyInsuranceExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X12PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X12ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X13MonthlyOtherExpenses__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X13PaymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X13ReducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X14_Council_Tax__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X14_Payments_continue_into_retirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X14_Reduce_payments_in_retirement_by__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X15regularMonthlySavings__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X15paymentsContinueIntoRetirement__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X15reducePaymentsInRetirementBy__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

        </lightning:tab>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

This is my other `recordEditForm` the one that is getting pushed over, I know that the same class is not applied to this code right now but when i d it breaks the other tabs to and makes them not the whole width of the modal.

Some screenshots of what it looks like: 
[image: working tab]

[image: broken tab]

Answer (score 0):

For the record form, can you try placing the `lightning:recordEditForm` inside of the `lightning:tab` rather than how it is right now?

Like this:

```
<lightning:tab label="Budget Planner" id="BudgetPlan">
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Budget_Planner__c" aura:id="budgetPlanner">
.
.
.
.
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</lightning:tab>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hiya mate, for the budget planner I can nest it inside the `lightning:tab` but for the factfind object I cannot do this due to needing multiple tabs inside the `recordEditForm` if I was to do this then I would need a `recordEditForm` inside each tab, wouldn't this affect the speed of the component and the save handler would be a pain right?